# RESTFB : How do I paginate the json result?

Tags: restfb

I have fetched the members of the public group from facebook using restfb apis. How do I get the data from the next page?

```
JsonObject groupMembersJson = facebookClient23.fetchObject("465940110177397", JsonObject.class,Parameter.with("fields", "members"));
```

I can use getConnection() method to get a Connection object and iterate over it. But, does it work on the user defined objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use `fetchConnection` instead.

It works with `JsonObject`, `String`, RestFB-builtin and custom types. Custom types needs to be implemented like defined in the manual with the `@Facebook` annotation on the fields that are filled by Facebook.